# Changing different HTML elements with each swipe of SwiperJS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new to javascript. I currently have a normal html page and I'm using a swiper JS element. Currently this is my code:

```
<head>
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"
    />
</head>

<body>
<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container mySwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>        
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>

<h1>Hello World</h1>

<!-- Swiper JS -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Swiper -->
<script>
  var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
    },
  });
</script>
```

Over here I have a `<h1>` tag that stays static. But I want it so that with each swipe of the Swiper Js element the content should also change respectively. For Example if the slide is currently in Slide 1 then the h1 should show Hello world 1, if its on Slide 2 then it should show Hello world 2 ...
Can someone please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `swiper.activeIndex` and update the `h1` tag innerhtml / innertext as per your needs.

if you are using react / angular / svelte then you need to set the state variable to `swiper.activeIndex`.